# Various transparent step in a line in a chart

Tags: excel, vba, transparency

I am using VBA with Excel 2013. I am developing a Macro with a chart, inside the chart there is a line made with a serie if points. I need apply a transparency shape to the steps between 2 point.

example 
1 to 2 solid
2 to 3 transparent
3 to 4 solid

With .transparency = 0 and 1 the shape is applied to the whole line. I tryed to apply .trasnparency various time but it is applied to the whole line.

How do I apply transparency to have the behauvior described above?

Comment: Record a Macro Understand and Adjust the code according to the need

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a gap is to insert a blank row between segments you want to be visible. In the top view below the data range is continuous, and so is the chart. In the bottom view, I've inserted blank rows between the X-Y values for the horizontal segments, and the chart rewards me with gaps in the plot, so the verticals don't show up.

[image: Step Chart With and Without Risers]

You can't get these gaps if your code is inserting arrays into the chart series source data, but you can use code like this to make them disappear (by using No Line instead of Transparency, personal preference):

```
Sub TransparentVerticals()
  Dim srs As Series
  Dim iPt As Long
  Set srs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
  For iPt = 1 To srs.Points.Count Step 2
    With srs.Points(iPt)
      .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```